# Google Sheets ArrayFormula in ArrayFormula

Tags: google-sheets

I have this formula:

```
=ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(IF((A8:A=A8)*(REGEXMATCH(E8:E; "\d{4}-\d{4}")); E8:E&" "&F8:F;)))
```

When I paste it in cell B8 and copy the Formula to B9, B10, B11 .... B1000 it counts perfect.

But I want to use a ArrayFormula in B8 to automatically expand the formula to all cells from B8:B1000.

I tried:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8<>1;ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(IF((A8:A=A8)*(REGEXMATCH(E8:E; "\d{4}-\d{4}")); E8:E&" "&F8:F;)));"")
```

but the array formula uses always the cell A8 to count.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A8<>1;ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(IF((A8:A=A8:A)*(REGEXMATCH(E8:E; "\d{4}-\d{4}")); E8:E&" "&F8:F;)));"")
```

and this counts the whole row A8:A

Is it possible to use my first posted ArrayFormula in a ArrayFormula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without further analysis, since there's no sample data; you could try inserting it into MAP:

```
=MAP(A8:A;LAMBDA(each;ArrayFormula(COUNTUNIQUE(IF((A8:A=each)*(REGEXMATCH(E8:E; "\d{4}-\d{4}")); E8:E&" "&F8:F;)))))
```